# Unable to display sort value , value missing

Tags: ibm-midrange, cobol

So currently i have made a cobol code that takes in my CustPF(physical file) which contains customer name, number , address and credit limit,etc . 
So i wanted to make a sort of my records that is contained in my CustPF , which is then done doing this

```
 PERFORM UNTIL WS-ENDCHECK = 'Y'                      
    SORT SORT-CUSTPF ON ASCENDING KEY S-EMPNO         
                     ON ASCENDING KEY S-CUNAME        
    USING CUSTPF                                      
    OUTPUT PROCEDURE IS 0002-SORTING-FILE             

 MOVE 'Y' TO WS-ENDCHECK                              
 END-PERFORM.
```

then it is read by doing this

```
RETURN SORT-CUSTPF INTO WS-CUSTPF                     
   AT END                                             
     DISPLAY 'READING OF FILE ENDED'                  
     DISPLAY 'TOTAL DISPLAY HERE'                     
     MOVE 'Y' TO WS-END-READ                          
   NOT END                                            
     CONTINUE                                                    
   DISPLAY all the values here
```

which then my results is displayed as this in the end

```
EMP NO: 000001      
CUSTOMER NAME: A    
ADDRESS: 34,ZZZZZZZ 
CREDIT LIMIT:   &
```

how is my credit limit appearing as & ?
sometimes it just displays blank ,- , a circle with a slash on it.

in my FD it is set as

```
05 WS-CUCRLM                   PIC 9(9)V99.
```

in my SD it is set as

```
05 S-CUCRLM                   PIC 9(9)V99.
```

in my custpf its format is this

```
CUCRLM         9P 2       TEXT('CUST CREDIT LIMIT')
```

Any idea how to make my credit limit display the numbers as normal ?
my credit limit examples are like     70000.00, 8000.00 , 600.00 , etc

Comment: @Joe Zitzelberger is correct that if you want to format your output an "normal" (whatever that may mean) you would need a editing PICture string (watch out for that .00 he shows). However, you'll need to unclobber your data first. Check that the FD and SD line up byte-for-byte first.

Comment: Does your sort procedure have any significant logic to justify using this method of sorting?  I can't remember how many years it's been since I've had a real cause to do this, and far longer since I've seen any colleagues do it.  Embedded SQL is normally the recommended technique for at least the last dozen years.  Even if you understand COBOL Sorts perfectly well, can you trust the person who works on this program after you will?  It may be time to modernize a bit.  (Just my own opinion).

Answer (score 4):

You will need an edited field to get things like commas and floating signs and decimal points.

It might also help to see your code that accumulates S-CUCRLM and WS-CUCRLM, but really, I just think you need a field defined like:

```
05 display-curlm  pic --9,999,999.00.
```

Answer (score 1):

It may be an issue with your input file. Ensure there are no funny characters in your input file and that all of the fields line up with your defines. Are there commas, negative values or decimals in your input file in that particular field? Is there anything common about the fields it is putting funny characters on (character length etc)?

If you have ruled out all of that, there are plenty of examples on using numeric data in cobol [here](http://www.pgrocer.net/Cis12/cobol3.html) that may be useful.

I hope this helps!

Comment: How is this an Answer rather than a Comment?